# Make gdb search for symbol files again

Tags: debugging, gdb, debug-symbols

My distribution (Debian) ships debug files in separate packages. So what happens often is that I run a program in `gdb` until it crashes, in order to obtain a usable backtrace for a bug report. But `bt` is rather useless, missing the symbol information – because I did not install the corresponding `-dbg` package.

If I install the package now, is there a way to make `gdb` search for the symbol files again, without losing my current backtrace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a trick you can use to make gdb try to read symbol files again:

```
(gdb) nosharedlibrary
(gdb) sharedlibrary
```

The first command tells it to forget all the symbol information it has, and the second command tells it to re-read it.

Comment: Will try that next time, but assuming it works, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to suggest an alternative approach with gdb `gcore` command, possibly it is suitable for you.

This is gcore description:

```
(gdb) help gcore
Save a core file with the current state of the debugged process.
Argument is optional filename.  Default filename is 'core.<process_id>'
```

So I have a program that causes a crash:

```
include <iostream>

int f()
{
  time_t curr_ts = time(0);
  std::cout << "Before crash " << curr_ts << std::endl;
  int * ptr = 0;
  *ptr = *ptr +1 ;
  std::cout << "After crash " << curr_ts << std::endl;
  return *ptr;
}

int main()
{

  std::cout << "Before f() " << std::endl;
  f();
  std::cout << "After f() "  << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with debug info. However I put the executable with debug info in an archive and for tests use a stripped version.

So it crashes under gdb:

```
$ gdb ./a.out                
Reading symbols from ./a.out...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/crash/a.out 
Before f() 
Before crash 1435322344

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040097d in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000040097d in ?? ()
#1  0x00000000004009e0 in ?? ()
#2  0x000000314981ed1d in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00000000004007f9 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007fffffffde58 in ?? ()
#5  0x000000000000001c in ?? ()
#6  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#7  0x00007fffffffe1a9 in ?? ()
#8  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) gcore crash2.core
Saved corefile crash2.core
```

I simply generate core file with `gcore` and leave gdb. Then I get from the archive the version with debug symbols and I can see all symbols:

```
$ gdb ./a.out ./crash2.core
Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.

warning: exec file is newer than core file.
[New LWP 15215]
Core was generated by `/home/crash/a.out'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x000000000040097d in f () at main.cpp:8
8     *ptr = *ptr +1 ;
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000040097d in f () at main.cpp:8
#1  0x00000000004009e0 in main () at main.cpp:17

(gdb) info locals 
curr_ts = 1435322344
ptr = 0x0
```

*Update*

if you `set backtrace past-main on` you will see at least this `__libc_start_main`. What is above `__libc_start_main` is not printed if you analyze only core file (possibly even not saved there) saved wit `gcore`:

```
$ gdb ./a.out crash2.core
Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.

warning: exec file is newer than core file.
[New LWP 15215]
Core was generated by `/home/crash/a.out'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x000000000040097d in f () at main.cpp:8
8     *ptr = *ptr +1 ;
(gdb) set backtrace past-main on
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000040097d in f () at main.cpp:8
#1  0x00000000004009e0 in main () at main.cpp:17
#2  0x000000314981ed1d in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Backtrace stopped: Cannot access memory at address 0x4007d0
(gdb)
```

But if I reproduce the crash under `gdb` with my test program (with debug info in it) I can see all (see `set backtrace past-main on` && `set backtrace past-entry on`):

```
$ gdb ./a.out 
Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/crash/a.out 
Before f() 
Before crash 1435328858

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040097d in f () at main.cpp:8
8     *ptr = *ptr +1 ;
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000040097d in f () at main.cpp:8
#1  0x00000000004009e0 in main () at main.cpp:17
(gdb) set backtrace past-main on
(gdb) set backtrace past-entry on
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000040097d in f () at main.cpp:8
#1  0x00000000004009e0 in main () at main.cpp:17
#2  0x000000314981ed1d in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00000000004007f9 in _start ()
#4  0x00007fffffffde58 in ?? ()
#5  0x000000000000001c in ?? ()
#6  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#7  0x00007fffffffe1a9 in ?? ()
#8  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

Comment: I actually tried that, but thought it did not work, because the backtrace was much shorter afterwards. But now I see that in your example, it is the same. Is that expected?

Comment: Updated my answer, yes it is expected. Use `set backtrace past-entry on` and `set backtrace past-main on` to get full backtrace. As you can see gdb by default hides stacktrace above main(). However when debug info is striped `gdb` does not do it.